# What is the '[Command Line]' that sometimes comes up when I try to quit, and how can I quickly exit it?

Tags: command-line

Occasionally when I try to quit Vim, I get something that looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how I accidentally invoke this, but my current method for escaping it is to hit random keys and eventually it goes away. Two questions:

- How am I invoking it (I use `:q` to exit vim) accidentally, and
- How can I exit it quickly and get back to what I'm working on?

Comment: I disable this keybinding/mode with `map q: <Nop>` in ~/.vimrc, as I find it very irritating, and never really use it.

Comment: PS: you can also `map q: :q`, which is probably even better.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have invoked it by pressing `q:` which opens a new window and allows you to write an Ex command. That is why it's called the `Command Line`

You can read up on it by typing `:help q:`.

As it is a window you can simply exit it as any other window, notably `:q` written correctly.

Comment: Moreover, the Command window is set up so that the command on the cursor line is executed when you press `Enter`, and your cursor will land on a empty line when you first open the Command window, so simply pressing `Enter` will close it.

Answer (score 7):

`:help Command-line`:

```
                        *Cmdline-mode* *Command-line-mode*
Command-line mode       *Cmdline* *Command-line* *mode-cmdline* *:*

Command-line mode is used to enter Ex commands (":"), search patterns
("/" and "?"), and filter commands ("!").
```

One of the ways to enter Command Line mode is `q:`, which you're probably accidentally typing.

This is simply a new window. You can close it via `<C-w> q`.

On a related note, I suggest using `ZZ` to save and quit instead. It's easier to type and less prone to mistakes like these.

Answer (score 2):

That view shows your recently used commands, you reversed the characters and pressed `q:` instead. You can use the default `<C-w> q` to close it.

Comment: This is true, yes, but it is more than that, actually. It is ex-mode in a repl-like shape.

Comment: I know it's the command line mode but I have strangely never used it like that. I use it to check the history `Shift V` to select a line and enter to execute again.